# How can i create one a string array of all this commands?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
Takeown  /f  D:\Windows /r  /D Y

Takeown  /f   "D:\Program Files"  /r  /D Y

Takeown  /f   "D:\Program Files(x86)"  /r  /D Y

Attrib  -s  -r  -h  D:\ProgramData

Takeown  /f   D:\ProgramData  /r  /D Y

Icacls  D:\Windows  /grant  %Username%:F   /t   /c

Icacls  "D:\Program Files"  /grant  %Username%:F   /t   /c

Icacls  "D:\Program Files(x86)"   /grant  %Username%:F   /t   /c

Icacls  D:\ProgramData  /grant  %Username%:F   /t   /c
```

I want later to be able to get acces to each command as a string for example:

```
"Icacls  "D:\Program Files(x86)"   /grant  %Username%:F   /t   /c"
```

I can make:

```
string[] params = new string[] {....};
```

But i'm getting messed up with the directories since some of them have to be between commas like: "D:\Program Files"

So far i tried this:

```
string[] commands = new string[] {
        "Takeown  /f  D:\\Windows /r  /D Y", "Takeown  /f   ""D:\Program Files""\  /r  /D Y"};
```

But getting errors on the part: "D:\Program Files""\  /r  /D Y"

> Syntax error, ',' expected
>   Unrecognized escape sequence
>   Error ',' expected
>   Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: What have you tried and what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape " in verbatim string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168961/how-do-i-escape-in-verbatim-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since double quotation marks conflict with string markup, you need to escape them. You can escape double quotation marks (as well as any other special symbol) by adding `\` in front. For example: `var str = "foo \"bar\""`.

In your context that would look like:
`string[] parameters = new string[] { "Icacls \"D:\Program Files(x86)\"   /grant %Username%:F /t /c" };`

P.S. `params` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a variable name.